# Андроид - Проблема с setAdapter в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

```
String[] names = {
        "Пример 1",
        "Пример 2",
        "Пример 3"
};

// находим список
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

// создаем адаптер
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

// присваиваем адаптер списку
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

При запуске приложения выходит ошибка. Смотрю в логах, где именно ошибка, перекидывает на строку с

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Что не так?
я работаю в navigation drawer,может  1 setAdapter связывается и с 2,и из-за  происходит ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: Скорее всего в лейаут не прицеплен или в лейауте нет идентификатора списка: `R.id.lv`

Comment: @anber, вы правильно подметили, что нужен хотя бы тип ошибки, молчу уже про стек трейс. Но меня лично улыбнуло именование фрагментов))

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. инициализация адаптера для списка выглядит нормально, то у вас скорее всего `NPE` при обращении к `ListView`. Видать в разметке активити нема этого `ListView` с `android:id="@+id/lv"`

Comment: Или как подвид этой же ошибки - в `setContentView()` указан неправильный id лаяута.